# How to avoid storing the username and password of the database in a config file? (PHP)

Tags: php, database, security

I developed an application in PHP. It has user authentication and works well.

I put the username and password of the database in a file called 'conf.php'. But I would avoid doing this and hide these data to reduce the possibility be victim of hackers.

How do I do this? or How do I protect these data?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? You have tagged 3 of them. I would strongly advise against storing passwords in plain text. They should be salted and hashed. You definitely should NOT be storing this in a file.

Comment: @SeanLange *They should be salted and hashed* The question is about the database password, not about users' passwords.

Comment: not possible. at **SOME** point you have to have the credentials stored somewhere, unless you want to sit in front of your server's console and manually enter them for every single hit on your site. just put the creds in a file that's outside of your site's document root and get on with life. if your machine's compromised to the point where someone can get that file, they'll also be able to get whatever's necessary to decrypt/de-obfuscate whatever you're done to hide the credentials in the first place.

Comment: I usually store the users/passwords on a file with an lesser  accessibility than the code itself, out of the server  root and version control software.  If your server is compromised and the attacker have access to this file probably he will be able to access your code and do some terrible things too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.

But, you can protect your config files from being accessible from the web.

For exemple, using apache config :

```
<FilesMatch "config\.php">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Or, you can put your config file outside of your public folder.

`WEBSITE
|- config.php
|- WWW <- Your virtualhost
   |- index.php`